# Redirect subdirectory to query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm not quite sure why this isn't working, but I keep getting either 404s or 500s. I'm trying to redirect subdirectories to the root directory with a query string tacked on. So if I go to `example.com/dir`, I will be redirected (behind the scenes, obviously) to `example.com/?url=dir`. I tried using this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule [^?](.+) ?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I thought it would get anything after the domain name that doesn't start with a query string (to prevent infinite redirect loops), and send it to the homepage with a query string tacked on. But it isn't working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule [^?](.+) ?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only. This never contains the query string (which is available in a separate server variable: `QUERY_STRING`).

You should also rewrite to the actual file that is handling the request. If you simply rewrite to `?page=$1` then you are relying on mod_dir to make an additional subrequest for the index document. If the index document is `index.php` then rewrite directly to that, ie. `index.php?page=$1`.

The above looks like it will result in a rewrite loop.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^page=
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?page=$1 [NS,L,QSA]
```

The preceding *condition* checks that the query string does not start with "page=".

The `NC` is not required here, since you are simply capturing everything, regardless of case.

The `NS` (`nosubrequest`) flag prevents the rule being called when mod_dir issues a subrequest for the directory index. In other words, it prevents a request for `example.com/` being internally rewritten to `index.php?page=index.php`.

Comment: Thanks! Works a charm, and I really appreciate the detailed answer too!